# Need to return only row with Max Start Date per Employee record

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I am building a query to return the latest data on an employee record - they can have multiple rows of data and I need it to filter based on the MAX start date for each row - I have looked online and tried to build as suggested but doesn't seem to be working

Basic version of what i tried would be:

```
select 

Tb1.PERSON_NO, Tb2.START_DATE 

from (Select Tb1.PERSON_NO, Tb2.START_DATE, (MAX)START_DATE OVER (PARTITION BY PERSON_NO) AS LATEST_START 

FROM Tb1 

INNER JOIN Tb2 on Tb1.PERSON_NO = Tb2.PERSON_NO)

WHERE Tb2.START_DATE = LATEST_START;
```

I also tried

```
SELECT Tb1.PERSON_NO, Tb2.START_DATE 
FROM Tb1 
INNER JOIN Tb2 on Tb1.PERSON_NO = Tb2.PERSON_NO
where (select MAX(Tb2.START_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY Tb1.PERSON_NO)) = Tb2.START_DATE;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group by for employee and take only maximum start date easily

```
select 

Tb1.PERSON_NO,
 max(Tb2.START_DATE)
 
FROM Tb1 

INNER JOIN Tb2 on Tb1.PERSON_NO = Tb2.PERSON_NO

GROUP BY
TB1.PERSON_NO
```

Comment: Thanks - that works with my basic query but when I have a more complex query i get not a GROUP BY expression.